# Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined , while making a google chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a *jquery.js* file defined under the `content_script` tag in my *manifest.json* file. Jquery.js runs as:

```
console.log('showMessage');
shows the expected string in console, but when I add
console.log($("p.js-tweet-text"));
```

It says that `$` is undefined. Can anyone help??

Comment: More info please. `console.log('showMessage');` actually outputting something merely means that your browser has a `console` attached to the `window` object - nothing to do with jQuery.

Comment: and if JQuery's good then kindly point out any other issues that might be there...

Comment: That doesn't mean jQuery is working, just that you have a console object :) Try typing `console.log(jQuery)` and see if that returns an object.

Comment: console.log function is used to write stuff in the console using which we can modify the content of the page as desired...such as if I have a div with class "k" and here "BAD" is the html text, then in console i write $("div.k").innerHTML = "good" and the text changes to "good"...
Now I am trying to write in console using my JQuery.js page. For this purpose console.log(input) function is used...when I write console.log('good'), then good is printed on console but console.log($("div.k").innerHTML = "bad") gives the error as explained above. Got it?

Comment: console.log(jQuery) yields "jQuery undefined" :(
Maybe I am being stupid because I am new at it. But please help me out of here somehow:P

Answer (score 3):

Two common gotchas. First, the order of scripts in `manifest.json` matters, so make sure jQuery is loaded first. Otherwise the `$` object might not be around when you ask for it:

```
{
  ...
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      ...
      "js": ["jquery.js", "my.js"]
    }
  ],
  ...
}
```

Second, remember [content scripts run in their own execution environment](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html#execution-environment), so you can't interact with objects defined in your content scripts from the browser environment (meaning the console).

Comment: Thiis is my manifest.json file
{
  "name": "Twitter Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "Let's start seriously!!!",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
  },
   "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://*/*"],
      "js": ["jquery.js" , "jquery.min.js"] 
    }
  ],
   "run_at": "document_start",
  "permissions": [
    "https://*/*"
  ]
}

Comment: and these two lines are in jquery.js

console.log('sdfdsf');
console.log($('p.js-tweet-text'));

Comment: From the order of the filenames, does this mean the jQuery library is `jquery.min.js` and comes after your own code in `jquery.js`? If you reverse the order the two files are loaded, does it affect your results?